# how to handle "not found (404)" page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

I want to add page 404.
I'm using https://github.com/kriasoft/universal-router for routing
But I do not know if I did it right or not.
To do this, I add the (.*) route:

```js
/* eslint-disable global-require */

// The top-level (parent) route
import { CheckForAuth } from "../actions/CustomApis/UsersApi";
import { CONTEXT_PATH } from "../constants/local-urls";
import UniversalRouter from 'universal-router'


const routes = {
  path: CONTEXT_PATH,

  // Keep in mind, routes are evaluated in order
  children: [
    {
      path: "/home",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'home' */ "./home"),
    },
    {
      path: "/message",
      load: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: 'message' */ "./message/create"),
    },
    {
      path: "/",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'login' */ "./login"),
    },

    {
      path: "/login",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'login' */ "./login"),
    },
    {
      path: "/forgetPassword",
      load: () =>
        import(/* webpackChunkName: 'forgetPassword' */ "./forgetPassword"),
    },

    {
      path: "/register",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'users' */ "./users/register"),
    },
    {
      path: "/profile",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'users' */ "./users/profile"),
    },
    {
      path: "/users/create",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'users' */ "./users/create"),
    },
    {
      path: "/users/update/:id",
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'users' */ "./users/update"),
    },
    // Wildcard routes, e.g. { path: '(.*)', ... } (must go last)

    {
      path: '(.*)',
     // action: () => <h1>Not Found</h1>
      load: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: 'not-found' */ "./not-found"),
    },
  ],

  async action({ next }) {
    // Execute each child route until one of them return the result
    const route = await next();

    // Provide default values for title, description etc.
    route.title = `${route.title || "Untitled Page"}`;
    route.description = route.description || "";
    return route;
  },
};

// The error page is available by permanent url for development mode

export default routes;
```

I also designed not-found.js
The following code is the contents of my router.js:

```js
import UniversalRouter from 'universal-router';
import routes from './routes';
import { goTo } from './util/generalUtil';

export default new UniversalRouter(routes, {
resolveRoute(context, params) {
if (typeof context.route.load === 'function') {
return context.route
.load()
.then(action => action.default(context, params));
}
if (typeof context.route.action === 'function') {
return context.route.action(context, params);
}
return undefined;
},
});
```

`
The following error occurs when testing undefined page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ki2EI.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right, it is the same logic mentioned within this doc too of the universal router package.
So for more details, you can refer to this link: https://github.com/kriasoft/universal-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md

[image]